# MVC Html.ValidationMessageFor is not firing in a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The Html.LabelFor works fine, so why not Html.ValidationMessageFor?
My partial view looks like;

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SHP.WebUI.Models.OtherLeaveViewModel>" %>
<% var unique = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(); %>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#EmployeeOtherLeave_OtherLeaveDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy' });
        $('#MorningOnlyFlag').click(function () {
            $('#AfternoonOnlyFlag').attr('checked', false);
        })
        $('#AfternoonOnlyFlag').click(function () {
            $('#MorningOnlyFlag').attr('checked', false);
        })
    });

    var options = {
        target: '#frmAddAbsenceOneDay<%= unique %>',
        success: RefershList
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#frmAddAbsenceOneDay<%= unique %>').ajaxForm(options);
    });

</script>

<div id="AddAbsenceOnDay<%= unique %>">
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("AddAbsenceOneDay", "Employee", FormMethod.Post,
           new { id = "frmAddAbsenceOneDay" + unique }))
       { %>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add an absence for a day or half day</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeOtherLeave.OtherLeaveId)%></td>
                    <td>
                <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeOtherLeave.OtherLeaveId, Model.LeaveList, "<--Select-->")%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeOtherLeave.OtherLeaveId)%>                    
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeOtherLeave.OtherLeaveDate)%>                    
                    </td>
                    <td>
                <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeOtherLeave.OtherLeaveDate)%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeOtherLeave.OtherLeaveDate)%>                    
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeOtherLeave.MorningOnlyFlag)%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.EmployeeOtherLeave.MorningOnlyFlag)%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeOtherLeave.MorningOnlyFlag)%>                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeOtherLeave.AfternoonOnlyFlag)%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.EmployeeOtherLeave.AfternoonOnlyFlag)%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeOtherLeave.AfternoonOnlyFlag)%>                     
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <p>
                <span style="padding-right:10px;"><input type="submit" value="Create" /></span><input type="button" value="Close" onclick="closeTab()" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    <% } %>
    </div>
```

My buddy class looks like;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SHP.WebUI.Utility;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SHP.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeOtherLeaf.Metadata))]
    public partial class EmployeeOtherLeaf
    {
        public string OtherLeaveName
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.OtherLeaf == null || this.OtherLeaf.OtherLeaveName == null)
                    return string.Empty;
                else
                    return this.OtherLeaf.OtherLeaveName;
            }
        }
        public EmployeeOtherLeaf() { }

        #region static methods

        #region methods

        #region "Buddy class" for validation
        /// <summary>
        /// This "buddy class" provides validation for a class generated from EF
        /// </summary>
        private sealed class Metadata
        {
            [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
            public int EmployeeOtherLeaveId { get; set; }
            [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
            public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

            [DisplayName("Leave Type")]
            [UIHint("DropDownList")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Leave Type is required")]
            public int OtherLeaveId { get; set; }

            [DisplayName("Date")]
            [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is required")]
            public DateTime OtherLeaveDate
            {
                get { return Convert.ToDateTime(this.OtherLeaveDate); }
                set { this.OtherLeaveDate = Convert.ToDateTime(value); }
            }

            [DisplayName("Morning Only")]
            public bool MorningOnlyFlag
            {
                get { return Convert.ToBoolean(this.MorningOnlyFlag); }
                set { this.MorningOnlyFlag = Convert.ToBoolean(value); }
            }

            [DisplayName("Afternoon Only")]
            public bool AfternoonOnlyFlag
            {
                get { return Convert.ToBoolean(this.AfternoonOnlyFlag); }
                set { this.AfternoonOnlyFlag = Convert.ToBoolean(value); }
            }
        }
        #endregion  
    }
}
```

*** ADDED INFO ***
I have since flattened the model and the new view looks like this;

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SHP.Models.EmployeeOtherLeaf>" %>
<% var unique = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(); %>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#EmployeeOtherLeave_OtherLeaveDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy' });
        $('#MorningOnlyFlag').click(function () {
            $('#AfternoonOnlyFlag').attr('checked', false);
        })
        $('#AfternoonOnlyFlag').click(function () {
            $('#MorningOnlyFlag').attr('checked', false);
        })
    });

    var options = {
        target: '#frmAddAbsenceOneDay<%= unique %>',
        success: RefershList
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#frmAddAbsenceOneDay<%= unique %>').ajaxForm(options);
    });

</script>

<div id="AddAbsenceOnDay<%= unique %>">
    <%Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("AddAbsenceOneDay", "Employee", FormMethod.Post,
           new { id = "frmAddAbsenceOneDay" + unique }))
       { %>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add an absence for a day or half day</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.OtherLeaveId)%></td>
                    <td>
                <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OtherLeaveId, Model.SelectLeaveTypeList, "<--Select-->")%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OtherLeaveId)%>                    
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.OtherLeaveDate)%>                    
                    </td>
                    <td>
                <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.OtherLeaveDate)%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OtherLeaveDate)%>                    
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.MorningOnlyFlag)%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MorningOnlyFlag)%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MorningOnlyFlag)%>                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.AfternoonOnlyFlag)%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AfternoonOnlyFlag)%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AfternoonOnlyFlag)%>                     
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <p>
                <span style="padding-right:10px;"><input type="submit" value="Create" /></span><input type="button" value="Close" onclick="closeTab()" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using this as a control?  How does this view get called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with the Javascript spelling mistake; RefershList should be RefreshList. I put that right and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata buddy class works alongside your regular model.  You should never actually access the members contained within the buddy class.

```
 <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.EmployeeOtherLeave.MorningOnlyFlag)%>
 <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeOtherLeave.MorningOnlyFlag)%>
```

Should be:

```
 <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MorningOnlyFlag)%>
 <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MorningOnlyFlag)%>
```

Whats happening you validate your actual model the ModelState entries probably contain keys like "*MorningOnlyFlag*". When you use the ValidationMessageFor with the metadata class members you  would be requesting ModelState entries with the key "*EmployeeOtherLeave.MorningOnlyFlag*".

---

You this is recursive right and will always throw a Stackoverflow exception?

```
public DateTime OtherLeaveDate
        {
            get { return Convert.ToDateTime(this.OtherLeaveDate); }
            set { this.OtherLeaveDate = Convert.ToDateTime(value); }
        }
```

---

Are you calling UpdateModel anywhere or using EmployeeOtherLeaf as the parameter as an action method? UpdateModel is what performs the model validation.

Comment: I have to admit that looked like the right answer. However I flattened the model and the validators still not not fire. See the new View above.